# Change margins for tcolorbox with varwidth environment

Tags: tcolorbox, varwidth

In the code posted below, I am using varwidth to shrink my tcolorbox to the text width for short text lines.  However, I also have some wraparound text lines and the tcolorbox is too big in that case.  How can I retain the shrink-to-fit behavior on short text snippets while changing the maximum margins of the tcolorbox?  I would like the maximum margins of the gray area to be slightly less than the regular paragraph margins on both sides, but I also want to keep is shrinking to fit when the text length is smaller than that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-2} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{varwidth} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newsavebox{\myboxbox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mybox}{+b}% find a better name
{%
    \centering
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    % measure the text width
    \sbox{\myboxbox}{\begin{varwidth}{\columnwidth}#1\end{varwidth}}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        breakable,
        width=\dimexpr\wd\myboxbox+8mm,
        top=3mm,
        bottom=4mm,
        ]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}{}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]\\

\begin{mybox}
    \begin{singlespace}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{singlespace}
\end{mybox}


\begin{mybox}
    \begin{singlespace}
        Just a few words here.  Just a few words here.
    \end{singlespace}
\end{mybox}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `varwidth` to `\dimexpr\columnwidth-8mm` to subtract off what you later add back to the `width` of the `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-2} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{varwidth} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newsavebox{\myboxbox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mybox}{+b}% find a better name
{%
    \centering
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    % measure the text width
    \sbox{\myboxbox}{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-8mm}#1\end{varwidth}}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        breakable,
        width=\dimexpr\wd\myboxbox+8mm,
        top=3mm,
        bottom=4mm,
        ]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}{}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]\\

\begin{mybox}
    \begin{singlespace}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{singlespace}
\end{mybox}


\begin{mybox}
    \begin{singlespace}
        Just a few words here.  Just a few words here.
    \end{singlespace}
\end{mybox}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  You are really cool!